# how to execute python script with command line using yml parsing in ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

Hi i have a script which i use to deploy artifacts, And we use command line to execute it. I need to deploy artifacts with Ansible using python script and command line.so i do not have idea how my yml file would be. I tried checking on some places but was not able to get correct format.

i tried and made `scriptname.yml` in playbook.

```
- hosts: control

  tasks:

  command '/usr/bin/python /usr/name/scriptname.py'
```

in this script location is `/usr/name/scriptname.py`

and command line would be like `./scriptname.py app`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after the script module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html). A script task would transfer your local file to the remote node and then execute it.

If the script already exists on the remote node, you should use a command task instead (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html).